# handlerror implementation in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the below code in my MVC application.

```
 [HandleError(View = "Error", ExceptionType = typeof(FormatException))]

    public ActionResult Indexerror()
    {
        throw new FormatException();  

    }
```

and a view named > error in the shared folder.
When I run this application I'm unable to see the view created, instead, a server error pops up in application with a message

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Kindly post a comment before suggesting to close. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that **CustomErrorMode** is **On** in web.config. That should be work, I did test.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On">
    </customErrors>
```